# How to hot backup (online backup) on a Slackware 14.2 with MariaDB 10.0.37?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, slackware

I'm trying mysqldump right now with the following script, but I need to verify that there are no locks in the process. What could I add to the code to confirm whether or not there are locks?

Script **input_mysql_bash_usuario.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
# serão inseridos um milhão de dados
while [ $i -le 1000000 ]
do
    mysql -uroot -pzabbix -e \
    “INSERT INTO usuario(nome,telefone,email,aniversario) VALUES(‘cesar,’9999999’,’cesarsj@unipam.edu.br’,’1993-11-18’) mysql_bash
    i=$(( i +1 ))
done
```

shell> nohup ./input_mysql_bash_usuario.sh > ./saida.log &

```
mysqldump --u<user> -p<password> <database> --single-transaction | gzip -c  | cat > $(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M.%S).sql.gz
```

I've tried before Percona XtraBackups 2.1.5, the package available in SlackBuils, but there were a lot of errors, I also saw that there is the Maria Backup, but it does not have on the MariaDb 10.0.37, which is from Slackware.

Comment: Wrong kind of quotes?  Unbalanced quotes?  What is `mysql_hash`?

Comment: Some "locks" are handled by "waiting"; this script does not seem to check for such.

Comment: Hello @RickJames, Thanks for the answer. I forgot to translate from Portuguese to English some words from the code. I'm from Brazil. But, mysql_bash is the database. 

How should I do this check?

Answer (score 0):

```
BEGIN;
SELECT * FROM mysql_bash.usuario LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE;
SELECT SLEEP(3600);  -- one hour; adjust as needed
COMMIT;
```

That might do the opposite of what you want -- namely verify that the dump can run even though you have a lock.